# GetElementsbyClassname: Open IE vs. MSXML2 Methods

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, getelementsbyclassname

The following macro works just fine.  It opens an instance of IE and uses the "getelementsbyclassname" method to return the expected value for "my_rate".  However when I run the second macro which uses the "MSXML2" method, the macro fails on the noted line and a "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method" error occurs.  Why does the "Open IE" method work, but the "MSXML2" method fail with my code?  I am running with IE 11.  I also have a reference set to the Microsoft HTML Object Library for the second macro, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Thanks in advance for explaining this to me.

```
Sub BankRate_Rate_Retrieval()
    my_url = "http://www.bankrate.com/funnel/mortgages/mortgage-results.aspx?market=321&loan=150000&perc=20&prods=2&points=0"   
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400
    End With

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    my_rate = ie.Document.getelementsbyclassname("br-col-2 br-apr")(1).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).innertext
End Sub


Sub BankRate_Rate_Retrieval()
    my_url = "http://www.bankrate.com/funnel/mortgages/mortgage-results.aspx?market=321&loan=150000&perc=20&prods=2&points=0"
    Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
    xml_obj.send
    html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.responseText
    Set xml_obj = Nothing

    my_rate = html_doc.body.getelementsbyclassname("br-col-2 br-apr")(1).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).innertext
```

' Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method occurs on above line

End Sub

Edit: Library Screenshot for D. Zemens

[image]

Comment: The HTML Object Library should work as long as you have IE9+. Eg `Dim doc As HTMLDocument` and then later in code `Set doc = New HTMLDocument:  doc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText`. Then `Set el = doc.getelementsbyclassname("br-col-2 br-apr")` should work okay?

Comment: Bingo, that works!  I did some further searching and found that it's a known early- vs. late-binding issue with getElementsByClassName and MSXML2.  My macro involved late-binding, your approach involves early-binding; only earl-binding works

Comment: I updated my IE from IE7 to IE11. Now getElementsByClassName works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty straightforward:

`GetElementsByClassName` is not a method available in the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library.

You can review the available methods, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926433.aspx

And while I can't find a similar documentation link, if you enable referenc to the MSHTML library, you can review there to confirm likewise, there is not `GetElementsByClassName` method.  This is a method that is available to IE automation but not to HTML or DOMDocument.

[image]

**UPDATED**

While this may not resolve your problem, I put it here in case it helps others with IE8.  It seems to be working for this purpose, but may need to be refined.

```
Option Explicit

Sub BankRate_Rate_Retrieval()
Dim my_url As String
Dim html_doc As Object 'HTMLDocument
Dim xml_obj As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim my_rate As String

my_url = "http://www.bankrate.com/funnel/mortgages/mortgage-results.aspx?market=321&loan=150000&perc=20&prods=2&points=0"

Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
xml_obj.send
html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.responseText

'attempt to replicate the GetElementsByClassName for IE8

my_rate = IE8_GetElementsByClassName(html_doc.body, "br-col-2 br-apr", 1).GetElementsByTagName("div")(0).InnerText

MsgBox my_rate


Set xml_obj = Nothing
Set html_doc = Nothing


End Sub

Function IE8_GetElementsByClassName(html As Object, className As String, Optional Position As Integer)
'Function to return an array of matching classname elements
' or if specified will return a single HTMLElement by Position index

Dim eleDict As Object
Dim ele as Variant
Set eleDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For x = 0 To html.all.Length - 1
    Set ele = html.all(x)
    If ele.className = className Then
        'Debug.Print i & vbTab & x & vbTab & ele.InnerText
        Set eleDict(i) = ele
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

If Position = Empty Then
    IE8_GetElementsByClassName = eleDict.Items
Else
    Set IE8_GetElementsByClassName = eleDict(Position)
End If
Set eleDict = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: My HTML Document class lists getElementsByClassName as a member.

Comment: Hmmmm... well I am not on same version/system as you so I may not be able to further assist.  I believe they added GetElementsByClassName with IE9+.  (I am using 8 so I cannot confirm this). Even the w3 standard for an HTMLDocument do not expose a GetElementsByClassName method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp  I added a new screenshot with more information, is yours the same (I'm wondering if you have an HTMLDocument that is a member of a different library than MSHTML).

Comment: Yes, I think they are the same library.  I edited my question and put a screen shot at the bottom

Comment: Sorry i didn't post the updated screenshot. It shold be there now. Make sure you can see that Class HTMLDocument member of MSHTML.

Comment: yep, they're the same library

Comment: perhaps the late binding is picking up an older version?

Comment: Can't say for sure. I made a function that attempts to replicate the GetElementsByClassName method, I will update my answer and you can try that out.

Comment: OK I have updated with my function. It seems to be working, but it will be slower since it's essentially a brute-force approach.