# Getting an ID of a class name tag in webbrowser

Tags: html, vb.net

So I got a web page that has the input tag

```
<div id="mainID" class="outside">
 <div class="inside">
  <input id="5443" name="43" type="checkbox" class="one" /> 
  <input id="5444" name="44" type="checkbox" class="one" /> 
  <input id="5445" name="45" type="checkbox" class="one" /> 
  <input id="5446" name="46" type="checkbox" class="one" /> 
  <input id="5447" name="47" type="checkbox" class="one" /> 
 </div>
</div>
```

The ID and name is varied, but the class name is always the same - so using the class tag ("one"), how can I retrieve the ID name, "5443" (well all of them one by one in a for loop) using the **visual basic browser**? I dont want the name tag information.

Comment: `getelementsbyclassname` should return a collection of elements matching a specified class name, do a loop over that collection in order to get the individual element `id`'s.

Comment: Sadly vb doesnt have elementsbyclassname, only elementsbytagname and ID. Tried putting them in a HtmlElementCollection and then getting the attribute but doesn't seem to work out...

Comment: Ahhh ok -- I would be surprised that there is no library you could import to parse DOM (rather than HTML, which doesn't have this method), but if that is the case, you could try to create a custom function that approximates that method. I think there is an example [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?536594-getElementsByClassName-Method).  I had to do something similar in VBA to support IE8 browser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476502/getelementsbyclassname-open-ie-vs-msxml2-methods/23477054#23477054), too.

Comment: if you're creating them in code-behind then just reference the variables directly. if not then reference a parent element by id, and loop through all child elements, selecting only those of the type that you want.