# Run-time error '424': Object Required IE.Document.GetElementById textbox inside iframe

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble loading text into a search box in IE using `IE.document.getElementbyID` I am including the code I am using so far. I am sure I am missing something here. This is an update of the iframe code I am including here

```
<iframe tabindex="-1" id="WorkdayApp" src="javascript:""" style="left: -1000px; top: -1000px; width: 0px; height: 0px; border-top-color: currentColor; border-right-color: currentColor; border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-left-color: currentColor; border-top-width: medium; border-right-width: medium; border-bottom-width: medium; border-left-width: medium; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; position: absolute;">

<input class="gwt-TextBox GPNS02MDDGJ" aria-label="Expanded, multiSelectPrompt, 0 items selected, Use up and down arrows to select. or Type in a search" type="text" placeholder="search" data-automation-id="searchBox"/>
```

"

```
 Sub workdayrep()

'*******************************
Dim iframe As Object
Dim textbox As Object
'*******************************
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
Set iframe = IE.document.getElementById("WorkdayApp")
Set textbox = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("searchBox")
IE.Visible = True


IE.navigate "https://wd.workday.com/142.htmld"

Application.StatusBar = "Page Loading" 

'Do While IE.Busy
'   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
' Loop
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
 textbox.Value = "TEST"

' Application.StatusBar = "Check"
End Sub
```

Comment: while I can't test it, I still suggest you use `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend` instead of `Application.Wait`... also, are you sure `IE.document.getElementById("searchBox")` returns just one object? just stop your code before your `getElementById` via `stop` or a breakpoint and put in your "watches" directly `IE.document.getElementById("searchBox")` and then check what it does return... I simply do not think that you can access it directly via `.Value`

Comment: I just looked at the code of the site I am trying to input the text is it loooks like it is inside an iframe                                                                                                                                                                                                               <input class="gwt-TextBox GPNS02MDDGJ" aria-label="Expanded, multiSelectPrompt, 0 items selected, Use up and down arrows to select. or Type in a search" type="text" placeholder="search" data-automation-id="searchBox"/>

Comment: Sometimes IE automation in VBA can be a little strange. You can try defining your search value as a string `Dim SV as String` `SV = "TEST"` then referring to this directly `IE.document.getElementById("searchBox").Value = SV` give that a try, I had to do a lot of this in my recent web scraping project.

Comment: Also `Dim IE as Object` not `Variant`

Comment: `IE.document.getElementById("searchBox").Value = "TEST"`  raises an error because some part of that namespace isn't (yet) an object. Most likely case is that `getElementById` returns a `Nothing`, which raises the 424 when attempting to assign to `Nothing.Value`... You need to wait for the page to finish loading using the method @DirkReichel mentions in comment, above.

Comment: @DavidZemens As it looks to me, The error is not due to the "not waiting enough time". While `Application.Wait` isn't the smart way, it still should work... From the beginning it looked much more like he simply isn't able to catch the right object. That said: this question isn't a dublicate to my eyes.

Comment: Re-opened esp. in light of additional information!

Answer (score 1):

The object you're trying to catch doesn't have an `ID` attribute, it has a `"data-automation-id"` attribute.

```
<input class="gwt-TextBox GPNS02MDDGJ" aria-label="Expanded, multiSelectPrompt, 0 items selected, Use up and down arrows to select. or Type in a search" type="text" placeholder="search" data-automation-id="searchBox"/>
```

As such, `getElementByID` will always return `Nothing` (unless there is some other element with that ID, which there obviously is not in this case!). You'll need a brute force loop over `getElementsByClassName("gwt-TextBox GPNS02MDDGJ")`, e.g. something like this (**untested**):

```
Dim itm
For each itm in iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("gwt-TextBox GPNS02MDDGJ")
    If itm.getAttribute("data-automation-id", 2) = "searchBox" Then
        itm.setAttribte("data-automation-id", "test")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yep I tried using the ElementsByClassName however this would only return with a Run-time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie) possible workaround for older versions of IE which don't support that method.

Comment: See also [this similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476502/getelementsbyclassname-open-ie-vs-msxml2-methods) (of mine) which may be easier to implement.