# Activating a search button via .Click

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I'm using IE11 with the HMTL Object Library and Internet Controls references activated.

There's no element ID on the button but am able to use `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName` by adding some html and xml declarations thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476502/getelementsbyclassname-open-ie-vs-msxml2-methods).

I'm taking a name and city, state from Excel and plugging it into the website then clicking the search button.

This is where my error occurs.

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

HTML:
[image]

VBA:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub HGScrape()
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
     'we define the essential variables
     Dim ie As Object
     Dim my_url As String
     Dim SearchButton, NameBox, AddressBox
     Dim ele As Object
     Dim x As Integer
     Dim y As Integer
     Dim IsOdd As Integer
     
     Dim html_doc As Object 'HTMLDocument
     Dim xml_obj As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
     
     my_url = "https://www.healthgrades.com/"
    
    'add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference in your VBA Project indirectly
     Set ie = New InternetExplorer
     ie.Visible = True 'False ''''''''''''''''''''''
     ie.Navigate my_url '"13.33.74.92"     '("https://www.healthgrades.com/")
     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
     Wend
         
     Set NameBox = ie.Document.getElementById("search-term-selector-child")
     NameBox.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
         
     Set AddressBox = ie.Document.getElementById("search-location-selector-child")
     AddressBox.Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
         
     Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
     Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

     xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
     xml_obj.send
     html_doc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
         
     Set SearchButton = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("autosuggest_submiter") 'id of the button control (HTML Control)
     SearchButton.Click
     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
     Wend
```

Comment: Can you try `ie.document.forms(0).Submit`?

Comment: And you stated that you made references to MS Internet Controls and to MS HTML  Obj Library - yet you are still declaring your variables as type `As Object`?

Comment: Looks like it just refreshed the page

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look

Comment: This post is using the `excel-vba` tag, which is [pending removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [should be replaced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) by `excel`and `vba`. But since it has already hit the five-tag limit, it's not possible to suggest that edit without removing at least one other tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I condensed your code a bit. You really do not need to set every element to a variable. This just wastes resources in the long run.

Use the ClassName `submiter__text` to grab your submit button, and it's index of `0`.

```
Sub HGScrape()

    Const sURL As String = "https://www.healthgrades.com/"

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    With ie

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate sURL
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .Document.getElementById("search-term-selector-child"). _
                    Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        .Document.getElementById("search-location-selector-child"). _
                    Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
        .Document.getElementsByClassName("submiter__text")(0).Click
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    End With

End Sub
```

> *"..Why was the "submitter_text" class the correct one?"*

The best way to explain it is to show you. If you are unsure what selection to make, then right-click the element and choose "Inspect Element" and look around the highlighted line.

[image]

Comment: Way more simple than what I had! Why was the "submitter_text" class the correct one?

Comment: Typically, the button element that you are wanting will not have any children. What that means, if there's a drop-down arrow to your element, then you haven't gone far enough.